# Mono assembly folders?

Tags: .net, mono, cross-platform

On a windows system the registry has keys like:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx

for locations of dot net assembly folders other than the gac.

Does a non-win mono system have a way of retrieving these or was it just considered not important?

Comment: Why should one want that? The installer is the one that installs Assemblies either in Applicationdirectory or in AssemblyCache - your Code does nothing have to do with these folders.

Comment: "your Code does nothing have to do with these folders" How can you know that. I never said anything about my code.

Comment: Then please explain why you need to know this location. Chances are you are doing something you shouldn't.

Comment: @skolima please don't tell me what I should and shouldn't do. Not everyone is like you. I have rewrote question.

Comment: I am not judging, I merely want to help. More context would be useful, because your problem is non-trivial.

Answer (score 5):

The registry is not cross platform. It is also not a good place to store your configuration data. DO NOT USE THE REGISTRY IN .NET UNLESS YOU ARE DEALING WITH LEGACY CODE.

The GAC is there to keep track of global assemblies for you in both Mono and .NET. Any local assemblies should be kept with the rest of your program.

If you really need these locations (and you shouldn't), then you should manually specify these locations in a configuration file.

Why are you looking for the physical location of an assembly that is in the GAC anyway?

Answer (score 3):

For starters, Mono on Linux stores the GAC as a list of files, paths, and links between the two. Most of the code which creates the base mono runtime utilizes a compile time flag named MONO_ASSEMBLIES. This value is set by default to $prefix/lib within the build system.

On most linux distros $prefix is set to "/usr", so `MONO_ASSEMBLIES` would be /usr/lib.
With this in mind, the actual base paths for the GAC is `$prefix/lib/mono/gac`. You can also set an environment variable for the mono (`MONO_GAC_PREFIX`) which allows you to set multiple base paths for the GAC.

As this path can be changed per install and mono allows for multiple paths utilizing an environment variable, you might need to get the base path of [Assembly.Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx). Also, [Assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.globalassemblycache.aspx) will help you determine if you need to check its path at all.

I hope this helps!